# Use row operations to find the inverse of C.

Tags: matrices

> Let $C=\begin{pmatrix}1&2&1\\ \:1&1&-1\\ \:0&3&2\end
> {pmatrix}$.
>   (a) Verify that $C$ has an inverse by finding its determinant.
>   (b) Use row operations to find the inverse of $C$.
>   (c) Check your answer by matrix multiplication.

Show that the Left matrix (C) can be row reduced to the Right matrix.

\begin{pmatrix}1&2&1\\ \:1&1&-1\\ \:0&3&2\end
{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\frac{5}{4}&-\frac{1}{4}&-\frac{3}{4}\\ \:-\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}\\ \:\frac{3}{4}&-\frac{3}{4}&-\frac{1}{4}\end{pmatrix}

Use R2-1xR1-->R2 as your first row operation.

Use R2x-1-->R2 as your 2nd row operation.

From there you are free to use row operations at your discretion.

I previously have answered this question by swapping R2 and R3 in my 2nd row operation and have been successful in getting the correct answer, but have been asked to do it with the above mentioned specificities and am finding it a bit more difficult to deduce the final answer.

Comment: What is R2-1xR1→R2?

Comment: can you describe the difficulty that you face in more details?

Comment: To echo @SiongThyeGoh, what exactly is the difficulty that you’re having? After the given two steps, the first column of the matrix is $(1,0,0)^T$, so you’re done with that, and you have a $1$ in the pivot position of the second column. That should make it quite simple to zero out the rest of that column and then proceed to the third. Just proceed systematically through the matrix.